# Vision-based Page Segmentation

Tags: php, jquery, html, algorithm, image-segmentation

I want implement a program that can do a a "Vision-based Page Segmentation". I need some guide and clue. (I need practical information and not just academical info)

My preferred languages are JS (jQuery) and PHP.

I read the following article (VIPS: a Vision-based Page Segmentation Algorithm) and I think it can be a good framework for this purpose:

ftp://ftp.research.microsoft.com/pub/tr/tr-2003-79.pdf

Is there any open source impementation for "Vision-based Page Segmentation"?

Comment: Wow, we have to read all that?

Comment: @elclanrs its idea is simple just skim it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. [*Microsoft Granted Patent on Vision-Based Document Segmentation (VIPS)*](http://www.seobythesea.com/2008/09/microsoft-granted-patent-on-vision-based-document-segmentation-vips/). Try again in 2023. I am truly sorry.

I am not a patent lawyer, but the [US patent 7,428,700](http://patft1.uspto.gov/netacgi/nph-Parser?Sect1=PTO1&Sect2=HITOFF&d=PALL&p=1&u=%2Fnetahtml%2FPTO%2Fsrchnum.htm&r=1&f=G&l=50&s1=7,428,700.PN.&OS=PN/7,428,700&RS=PN/7,428,700) claims are quite straightforward:

> 1. A method implemented at least in part by a computing device of identifying one or more portions of a document described by a tree structure having a plurality of nodes, the method comprising: identifying a plurality of visual blocks in the document based on, at least, a document model of the document; detecting, distinct from the plurality of visual blocks, one or more separators of the document based on, at least, one or more characteristics of at least one of the plurality of visual blocks; assigning, to each of the one or more separators, a weight based on characteristics of visual blocks on either side of the separator; and constructing, based at least in part on the plurality of visual blocks and the one or more separators, a content structure for the document, wherein the content structure identifies the different visual blocks as different portions of semantic content of the document.

Now, *a document described by a tree structure having a plurality of nodes* is our old friend DOM model of a Web page.

Also note that the four inventors are also the same four co-authors of the paper cited. I be damned if that's a sheer coincidence.

Comment: forgot VIPS. Our purpose is just Page Segmentation.

Comment: @Reza: I googled it up for you. I read it for you. I gave you the most concise abstract possible. Now you are arguing with me that "HTML Document" is not same as "HTML Page". I am not a patent court, and you are arguing your case before a wrong judge, sorry.

Comment: @Reza: I added a citation from the patent. Looks, well... *it*.

Comment: Thanks kkm for your information. I do not live in US. Did you mean in your country if a guy segment a webpage in some manner and patent it, no body else can do web page visual segmentation in any other method?! As I know more than 100 paper suggest other page segmentation method based on VIPS.
Aside from that I don' want use VIPS algorithm at all, I just mentioned it for clarify purpose.

Comment: @Reza: this is a very complex question, and you need a patent lawyer to answer it. The idea is that patent should be narrow enough, and cover a specific invention. So it is very unlikely for a patent that covers *just any* way of splitting the page to be able to stand up in court.

Comment: @Reza: As far as I understand, patents are national, and I do not know if there exist international mutual agreements on patent rights. And, most certainly, in a locality where the patent does not apply, it cannot by itself prevent you from using the invention commercially. Also, you normally can implement the algorithm for research purposes, and publish papers on it (patents actually exist to encourage free exchange of information), but you cannot apply it commercially--and an open-source library competing with a commercial one is most likely a commercial use.